# maven test scope transitive dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am writing a plugin where I need to get all the dependency artifacts of a project including `test` scope and all of the transitive dependencies as well. `project.artifacts` seems to get me all the dependencies if I run the plugin in the install phase (I cannot run it before that), except it does not get me test scope dependencies and any transitive dependencies of these `test` scope dependencies. How do I get the transitive dependencies of everything?

I have also tried `project.dependencyArtifacts` which doesn't seem to help. It gets the test scope direct dependency but not the transitive ones.

Working with `maven 2.0.9`

Comment: `2.0.9` is pretty old and the issue you reported might be fixed in newer versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting for reference:

I had to set `@requiresDependencyResolution test` which then included all the transitive dependencies. It was initially set to `runtime`. This fixed my issue.